# Tool which was used for conversion DOC ( Word file ) to html

Tags: html, doc

I am having a difficulty to recall what I used a couple of years ago to convert doc to html.
It gave me the best results comparing to other tools and Save as in Word.

Generated html contains inside( it is the only distinct tag I could find )

```
<meta content="TX15_HTM 15.0.300.502" name="GENERATOR" />
```

Looks like a reference to text control

http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/

I am quite sure , I didn't write any code to drive it, which means it was a tool which probably uses it internally. What would it be ?

Comment: It was something different, but TXWords included into different products from Text Control e.g. Text Control ActiveX does help.  In TXWords you may open Word document and save as Html. 

Also 

http://www.word-converter.net/ 

uses internally text control.
If anyone knows other products converting word to html wiit text control please add to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Though this ISN`T a direct answer to your question, it might help you.

You can save (in "save as" => "other formats") as html which does it (quite) decently* most of the times, this of couse isnt done programatically if that is what you ment.

Good luck, hope it helps!!

*This will be controversial I guess and I`ll admit many times it is really bad but IMHO depends on the use youll give it.